# Is there a way to intercept RPC calls to UNIMPLEMENTED RPC

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

I made a change to the `.proto` file where the path of a method changed

old `.proto`

```
package foo

rpc test
```

Method path is `foo.test`

new `.proto`

```
package foo.v1

rpc test
```

Method path is `foo.v1.test`

Of course, old clients will stop working with error

```
12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service foo.test
```

I don't want to version my APIs instead I want to run a server interceptor that fixes the path for each incoming request.

The issue is the client gets an error response `UNIMPLEMENTED` before the request is handled by the interceptor.

To my understanding, the interceptor function is executed before the handler but, it seems there is code running that check the connection and the method name before the interceptor.

My question is how to get the server interceptor to run first and change the method path?

Ps. the cleint uses `grpc-js`

Comment: Unfortunately the interceptors only execute for known services. If you want a customized way to handle unknown services, try https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#section-readme

Comment: Sorry, just realize that I posted the wrong link. It should be the unknown service handlers: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#UnknownServiceHandler

Answer (score 0):

The method path can't be changed after call method.  The interceptor execute later than find method by service and method name. So you should not remove the origin method when any client still call this method.